# Inner loop exceeding maximum index value

Tags: loops, for-loop, nested-loops, carriage-return

I'm running some code on the command line that should execute some simple code inside a double nested loop, along with some `printf`-ing to track my progress:

```
for i in {1..180}; do for j in {1..200}; do
printf "$i-$j\r";
if [[ ! -f $dir/$i/$j/file0 ]] || [[ ! -f $dir/$i/$j/file1 ]]; then
echo $j >> $i.missing;
fi; done; done
```

To my great surprise, I see the inner loop index `$j` is reaching well over 200 - I've seen it go as high as 960. This may explain why this code is running so painfully slowly. I'm not really sure what mistake I've made here - does nesting loops in bash not work the way I think it does?

Comment: I simply ran 2 for loops and simply printed text and it worked fine for me, are you having Control M characters in your script? Could you please check once by doing `cat -v Input_file`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here has nothing to do with loops, but lies with the use of the `\r` character in `printf`. The print isn't clearing the line, just moving back to the beginning of it - so when you reach `1-200`, the next hundred print statements won't clear out all the terminal zeros, thus `2-96` appears to be `2-960`. In other words, there's nothing wrong with the code, just the way progress is being reported.

There are a number of easy fixes:

1. Replace `\r` with `\n`, though this would no longer produce the desired behavior of updating a single line of output
2. Clear each line before printing, `printf "\r[many spaces]\r$i-$j`
3. Print the numbers with a fixed width (left padding with zeros): `printf "\r%03d-%03d" $i $j`

Comment: Ahhhh I found it almost correctly, see my answer too :) cheers.